# How to set values of an object from one of two sources

Tags: php, oop

Right now I'm trying to tackle the problem of dealing with data either a) from the Facebook Graph API or  b) provided by the user manually through form submission. To keep it simple, this is how I'm currently setting up the class, not accounting for a manual form submission:

```
class user {

public $collegemajor;

public function __construct($collegemajor)

$this->collegemajor = $collegemajor;

$collegemajor = isset($user_profile['education'][0]['concentration'][0]['name']) ? $user_profile['education'][0]['concentration'][0]['name'] : null ;
$objUser = new user ($collegemajor);

}
```

And here is roughly what I'm trying to do. Keep in mind I haven't used getter or setter methods yet in the app. The goal is to set $collegemajor as the Graph API value if it's available or as the posted form submission if the API data isn't available. Assume if the data isn't available from the API, the user has already submitted the major via form. What is the best way to do this? Is it a getter and setter method? If so I'm lost on how I would construct it. How about adding it to this line:

```
$collegemajor = isset($user_profile['education'][0]['concentration'][0]['name']) ? $user_profile['education'][0]['concentration'][0]['name'] : null ;
```

The value of the form submission, if it exists, would be something like this:

```
$_POST['major'];
```

Here's my failed attempt below. It didn't return the form submitted value as planned. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
class user {

public $collegemajor;

public function __set($collegemajor, $value) {
        if (isset($this->collegemajor)) {
            return $this->collegemajor;
        } else {
            return $_POST['major'];
        }
    }

public function __construct($collegemajor) {

$this->collegemajor = $collegemajor;

}

public function echos () {
    echo "$this->collegemajor";
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object is trying to take on more responsibility than it should.  Your user object should only manage the data pertaining to a given user, it should not try to implement various ways of getting that data.

The correct approach is to have a class that fetches data from a source and presents it in a standardized format for your user class to use.  This uncouples the task of managing a user from the task of getting data into the user class, and is considered to be better OOP practice.